# python3, класс bytes, как получить нулями и единицами

Tags: python-3.x

Получаю данные по COM-порту, используя pySerial, и он возвращает данные типа bytes, щас использую str(), чтобы прочесть их ,но получается что-то типа b'H' - как можно получить представление в виде единиц и нулей?

Comment: А зачем вам нули и единицы? Выводите как hex() :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def b2a_bin(data):
    return bin(int.from_bytes(data, 'big'))[2:].zfill(8*len(data)) if data else ''
```

Пример:

```
>>> b2a_bin(b'H\1\0')
'010010000000000100000000'
```

На [Cython реализация](https://gist.github.com/zed/3526111).